# В SCSS выполнить break

Tags: css, scss

Есть такой код.

Pug:

```
div(data-counter="100")
```

SCSS:

```
$start: 100;
$end: 20;

div:before {
  content: attr(data-counter);
  animation: countdown 10s steps(1, start) forwards;
}

@keyframes countdown {
  @for $i from 1 through $start { 
    @if $i == 50 {
      100% {
        content: 'Stop';
      }
    } @else {
      #{$i}% {
        content: '#{($start - $i)}';
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Задача в том, что счетчик отсчитывает со `100` и при достижении `50`-и счетчик бы останавливался, т.е `100% { content: 'Stop'; }` и анимация бы заканчивалась (сейчас она продолжается `49% { content: '51'; } 100% { content: 'Stop'; } 51% { content: '49'; }`).

**Вопрос:**  Есть ли для scss что-то вроде `break;` как в js?

[Пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/Pjggbv).

**P.S:** `@break;` не срабатывает как хотелось бы.

PPS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45158695/6452878)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать гораздо проще:

```css
div {
  line-height: 1.2;
  height: 1.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: "100\A 99\A 98\A 97\A 96\A 95\A 94\A 93\A 92\A 91\A 90\A 89\A 88\A 87\A 86\A 85\A 84\A 83\A 82\A 81\A 80\A 79\A 78\A 77\A 76\A 75\A 74\A 73\A 72\A 71\A 70\A 69\A 68\A 67\A 66\A 65\A 64\A 63\A 62\A 61\A 60\A 59\A 58\A 57\A 56\A 55\A 54\A 53\A 52\A 51\A Stop";
  animation: move-up 10s steps(50) 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes move-up {
  from { transform: translateY(0) }
  to   { transform: translateY(calc(1.2em - 100%)) }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: не особо проще, потому что в контенте  писать всю строку вот эту ""100\A 99\A 98\A 97\A 96\A 95\A 94\A 93\ ... "  да и вопрос больше о прекращении цикла нежели о таймере, но за решение спасибо все равно!

Comment: @HamSter, эта строка в контенте намного короче, чем то, во что развернётся scss-код. А саму строку я быстренько получил на js в консоли браузера: `s = '';
for (q=100; q>50; --q) s+=q+'\\A '` - только Stop потом дописал.

Answer (score 0):

[Из комментария на so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158695/execute-the-break-in-scss)

Решение заключается в замене знака сравнения `==` на знак больше `>`:

Pug:

```
div(data-counter="100")
```

SCSS:

```
$start: 100;
$end: 20;

div:before {
  content: attr(data-counter);
  animation: countdown 10s steps(1, start) forwards;
}

@keyframes countdown {
  @for $i from 1 through $start { 
    @if $i > 50 {
      100% {
        content: 'Stop';
      }
    } @else {
      #{$i}% {
        content: '#{($start - $i)}';
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Это действительно **работает**, хотя и компилирует не совсем как хотелось бы, css:

```
  ...
  100% {
    content: 'Stop';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'Stop';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'Stop';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'Stop';
  }
  ...
```